# How to disable the aero shake for whole system?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a simple WPF application for enable and disable the aero shake behavior. My code is like this:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestDisableShaking
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        const uint DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION = 0;
        const uint DWM_EC_ENABLECOMPOSITION = 1;

        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DwmEnableComposition")]
        extern static uint DwmEnableComposition(uint compositionAction);

        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DwmEnableComposition")]
        protected static extern uint Win32DwmEnableComposition(uint uCompositionAction);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION);
            Win32DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION);
        }
    }
}
```

Why my code does not function?

**What this application do now:**
When I shake my window, the others windows are minimized.

**What I want to do:**
When I shake my window, or I shake any window, no window should be minimized.

Comment: Did you check the returns from those function calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint iAction, uint iParameter, ref uint pParameter, uint iWinIni);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint iAction, uint iParameter, uint pParameter, uint iWinIni);
```

and

```
SystemParametersInfo(0x0083, (Convert.ToUInt32(0)), (Convert.ToUInt32(0)), Convert.ToUInt32(1));
```

Comment: How did you figured this out ?